# Youtube grant permissions message displayed twice

Tags: youtube

While Authorizing an application registered with `youtube`, for server-side flow I am getting two identical grant permission messages displayed on authorization page.

Scopes used in app are:`("http://gdata.youtube.com,http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com")`

Is it possible to get single grant permission message for two scopes mentioned above?